# Value won't be written into database

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

following value won't be written into database, although var_dump shows value correctly.

```
$model=new Bewerber();
$model->umkreis=5000;
$model->wunschgehalt_brutto=7777; 

var_dump($model->umkreis)
```

shows up

```
int(5000)
```

but value won't be written into databse. How can this be?
Here is model:

```html
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\bewerber\models\base;

use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\behaviors\BlameableBehavior;
use mootensai\behaviors\UUIDBehavior;

class Bewerber extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

    use \mootensai\relation\RelationTrait;

    public $avatar;

    public function relationNames() {
        return [
            'person',
            'abrechnungsweg',
            'bewerberquelle',
            'kanal',
            'personRekrutiertVon',
            'angelegtVon',
            'aktualisiertVon',
            'bewerbungVorschlags',
            'eMatchingbegriffs',
            'ePhases',
            'eStatuses',
            'user0',
            'user1'
        ];
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['id_person', 'id_person_rekrutiert_von', 'id_abrechnungsweg', 'id_kanal', 'id_bewerberquelle', 'id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_1', 'id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_2', 'id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_3', 'umkreis', 'avgs', 'avgs_betrag', 'wunschgehalt_brutto', 'arbeitsumfang_vollzeit', 'arbeitsumfang_teilzeit', 'arbeitszeit_bueroueblich', 'arbeitszeit_vormittag', 'arbeitszeit_nachmittag', 'arbeitszeit_abend', 'arbeitszeit_nacht', 'arbeitszeit_wochenende', 'schichtbereitschaft', 'wochenstunden_minimum', 'wochenstunden_maximum', 'quereinsteiger', 'zeitarbeit', 'pkw', 'fuehrerschein_pkw', 'fuehrerschein_lkw', 'fuehrerschein_omnibus', 'reisebereitschaft', 'kandidat', 'veroeffentlichen_bewerberboerse', 'kontakt_halten', 'aktiv', 'angelegt_von', 'aktualisiert_von', 'optimistic_lock'], 'integer'],
            [['ablaufdatum_avgs', 'verfuegbar_ab', 'kandidat_seit', 'zuletzt_deaktiviert_am', 'angelegt_am', 'arbeitsuchend_seit'], 'safe'],
            [['beurteilung_fachlich', 'beurteilung_persoenlich', 'sonstiges', 'anschreiben'], 'string'],
            [['gesuchte_positionen', 'bemerkung_intern'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['id_person', 'avgs', 'arbeitsumfang_vollzeit', 'arbeitszeit_bueroueblich', 'kandidat', 'veroeffentlichen_bewerberboerse', 'kontakt_halten', 'aktiv'], 'required'],
            ['avgs_betrag', 'default', 'value' => '2000'],
            [['optimistic_lock'], 'default', 'value' => '0'],
            [['optimistic_lock'], 'mootensai\components\OptimisticLockValidator'],
            [['avatar'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'maxFiles' => 3],
        ];
    }

    public static function tableName() {
        return 'bewerber';
    }

    public function optimisticLock() {
        return 'optimistic_lock';
    }

    public function attributeLabels() {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
            'id_person' => Yii::t('app', 'Bewerber'),
            'id_person_rekrutiert_von' => Yii::t('app', 'Bewerber wurde rekrutiert von'),
            'id_abrechnungsweg' => Yii::t('app', 'Abrechnungsweg'),
            'id_kanal' => Yii::t('app', 'Kanal'),
            'id_bewerberquelle' => Yii::t('app', 'Bewerberquelle'),
            'id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_1' => Yii::t('app', 'Gelernter Beruf'),
            'id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_2' => Yii::t('app', 'Alternativ Beruf'),
            'id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_3' => Yii::t('app', 'ungelernte Tätigkeit'),
            'umkreis' => Yii::t('app', 'Umkreis(km)'),
            'arbeitsuchend_seit' => Yii::t('app', 'Arbeitsuchend seit'),
            'avgs' => Yii::t('app', 'Avgs'),
            'avgs_betrag' => Yii::t('app', 'Avgs-Betrag'),
            'ablaufdatum_avgs' => Yii::t('app', 'Ablaufdatum(Avgs)'),
            'wunschgehalt_brutto' => Yii::t('app', 'Wunschgehalt(brutto/€)'),
            'beurteilung_fachlich' => Yii::t('app', 'Beurteilung(fachlich)'),
            'beurteilung_persoenlich' => Yii::t('app', 'Beurteilung(persönlich)'),
            'sonstiges' => Yii::t('app', 'Sonstiges'),
            'verfuegbar_ab' => Yii::t('app', 'Verfügbar ab'),
            'gesuchte_positionen' => Yii::t('app', 'Gesuchte Positionen'),
            'anschreiben' => Yii::t('app', 'Anschreiben'),
            'arbeitsumfang_vollzeit' => Yii::t('app', 'Arbeitsumfang(VZ)'),
            'arbeitsumfang_teilzeit' => Yii::t('app', 'Arbeitsumfang(TZ)'),
            'arbeitszeit_bueroueblich' => Yii::t('app', 'ArbZ/8-16pm.'),
            'arbeitszeit_vormittag' => Yii::t('app', 'ArbZ(vorm.)'),
            'arbeitszeit_nachmittag' => Yii::t('app', 'ArbZ(Nachm.)'),
            'arbeitszeit_abend' => Yii::t('app', 'ArbZ(abds.)'),
            'arbeitszeit_nacht' => Yii::t('app', 'ArbZ(nachts)'),
            'arbeitszeit_wochenende' => Yii::t('app', 'ArbZ(WE)'),
            'schichtbereitschaft' => Yii::t('app', 'schichtbereit'),
            'wochenstunden_minimum' => Yii::t('app', 'WStd.(min.)'),
            'wochenstunden_maximum' => Yii::t('app', 'WStd.(max.)'),
            'bemerkung_intern' => Yii::t('app', 'interne Bemerkung'),
            'quereinsteiger' => Yii::t('app', 'Quereinsteiger'),
            'zeitarbeit' => Yii::t('app', 'Zeitarbeit'),
            'pkw' => Yii::t('app', 'Pkw'),
            'fuehrerschein_pkw' => Yii::t('app', 'FS(Pkw'),
            'fuehrerschein_lkw' => Yii::t('app', 'FS(Lkw)'),
            'fuehrerschein_omnibus' => Yii::t('app', 'FS(Bus)'),
            'reisebereitschaft' => Yii::t('app', 'reisebereit'),
            'kandidat' => Yii::t('app', 'Kandidat'),
            'kandidat_seit' => Yii::t('app', 'Kandidat seit'),
            'veroeffentlichen_bewerberboerse' => Yii::t('app', 'Bewerberbörse'),
            'kontakt_halten' => Yii::t('app', 'Kontakt halten'),
            'aktiv' => Yii::t('app', 'Aktiv'),
            'zuletzt_deaktiviert_am' => Yii::t('app', 'Zuletzt deaktiviert am'),
            'angelegt_am' => Yii::t('app', 'Angelegt am'),
            'angelegt_von' => Yii::t('app', 'Angelegt von'),
            'aktualisiert_am' => Yii::t('app', 'Aktualisiert am'),
            'aktualisiert_von' => Yii::t('app', 'Aktualisiert von'),
            'optimistic_lock' => Yii::t('app', 'Optimistic Lock'),
        ];
    }

    public function getPerson() {
        return $this->hasOne(\common\modules\basis\models\Person::className(), ['id' => 'id_person']);
    }

    public function getAbrechnungsweg() {
        return $this->hasOne(\common\modules\lookup\models\LAbrechnungsweg::className(), ['id' => 'id_abrechnungsweg']);
    }



    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'createdAtAttribute' => 'angelegt_am',
                'updatedAtAttribute' => 'aktualisiert_am',
                'value' => new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()'),
            ],
            /* das Blameable-Verhalten wurde in unsere Klasse ausgelagert */
            'uuid' => [
                'class' => UUIDBehavior::className(),
                'column' => 'id',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public static function find() {
        return new \frontend\modules\bewerber\models\BewerberQuery(get_called_class());
    }


    public function upload() {
        $x=0;
        if ($this->validate()) {
            foreach ($this->avatar as $uploaded_file) {
                $uploaded_file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@uploading') . '/' . $uploaded_file->baseName . '.' . $uploaded_file->extension);
                $x++;
            }
            if($x>0)
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Didn't saved your model anywhere? Controller?

Comment: You need to call $model->save();